# How to convert the Date format and store it in a Date field(not in string or println) with the new format in Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I'm trying to get the date from an object and changing the format and down the line I need to use the date value as a date field itself(not as string).

The format is getting changed by using format() method of SimpleDateFormat. But the default format is getting used when we assign this string value back to the date field by using parse() method of SimpleDateFormat. 
Uses Spring MVC and need to pass this date-MM/dd/yyyy to the JSP file as a model attribute.

PFB code and the comments for the date format generated after processing that line.

```
Date date1 = student.getDateOfBirth();        // Tue May 16 00:00:00 IST 2017
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(date1);    // 05/16/2017
Date date2 = format.parse(dateStr);           // Tue May 16 00:00:00 IST 2017
student.setDateOfBirth(date2);
```

Comment: A date-time object is *not* a String, and has no format.

Comment: Study some of [the six thousand  existing Questions and Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Java+date+format) on this topic before posting.

Answer (score 2):

A `Date` object doesn't have *any* state representing a format. [It's *just* an instant in time](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/). If you've got the right value in `date1`, then formatting and parsing it is completely pointless.

Instead, when you want the `Date` in a particular format later on, you should format it *there*. (Note that you should decide which time zone you're interested in, too.)

Comment: Thanks Jon for the response. 
Do you mean we can not store a date in the date field with the format- "MM/dd/yyyy"?

Comment: @JeromeJoseph: If the type of the field is `Date`, then no - all you can store is an instant in time. If it helps, think of it as being like an `int` field - you can't say "I want to store this `int` in hex" or "I want to store this `int` in binary" - it's just an integer.